# Can I convert SQL update statement to HQL where I have multiple rows to update?

Tags: hibernate, hql

My problems looks something like the following.

- Notice the bold part.

  *update tableName set tableName.fid = '10' where tableName.pid **IN** (:'1','2','3');*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198636/how-to-convert-nested-sql-to-hql

Answer (score 0):

```
String hqlUpdate = "update Customer c set c.name = :newName where c.name = :oldName";
```

Please see "[Hibernate Reference Documentation: DML-style operations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct)"

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think you haven't noticed the IN statement. Basically updating multiple rows with their own specific criteria is where my problem revolves.